# Mostrar array json de imágenes

Tags: html, json, array, angular6

He creado un array de imágenes en angular 6, pero cuando voy a mostrarlo en la plantilla no se me muestra.

Aquí dejo mi código ts

```
public images=[
    {src:'assets/img/28.png'},
    {src:'assets/img/53.png'},
    {src:'assets/img/43.png'}
  ];
```

y mi HTML

```
<img src="{{images.src}}" alt=""/>
```

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer las imágenes e ir obteniendo la propiedad del item del array, un ejemplo sería:

```
<div *ngFor="let image in images">
   <img [src]="image.src" alt="">
</div>
```

Además angular nos permite bindar el atributo src de image a una propiedad indicando directamente `[src]` y el la propiedad ha ser bindada.

Comment: Cierto, se me había olvidado el ngFor, muchas gracias